# How do I generate sequential numbers in PHP starting from 1 and insert them into a table?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to insert a sequential number after each recurring total elemnts (`<th rowspan=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Recurring Total', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>`), starting from 1, then going 2,3,4, ...

It should number all the items for the purpose of more clarity. here's the code and below an image what i try to reach.

```
<tr class="order-total recurring-total">
    <?php if ( $display_th ) : $display_th = false; ?>
        <th rowspan=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Recurring Total', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
        <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Recurring Total', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?>"><?php wcs_cart_totals_order_total_html( $recurring_cart ); ?></td>
    <?php else : ?>
        <th rowspan=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Recurring Total', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
        <td><?php wcs_cart_totals_order_total_html( $recurring_cart ); ?></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tr>
```

Here is an image what I seek to accomplish; "wiederkehrende gesamtsumme" = recurring total

[image]

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, create a variable before the loop that prints out the table rows: `$counter = 1;` and then just print it where you want it in your table: `<?= $counter++ ?>`. That will print the current value and increment it with one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works just fine! Perhaps I may ask if there is a similar simple way of showing the numbers like 1/3, 2/3, ...

Comment: As long as you know the total, just add it: `<?= $counter++ . '/' . $total ?>`

Comment: no i didnt know the total, but this $total = count($recurring_carts) before the loop solved the problem. thanks again for the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use for loop and print table-rows in the loop

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= $n ; $i++) { ?>
<tr class="order-total recurring-total">
        <?php if ( $display_th ) : $display_th = false; ?>
            <th rowspan=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Recurring Total', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Recurring Total', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?>"><?php wcs_cart_totals_order_total_html( $recurring_cart ); ?></td>
        <?php else : ?>
            <th rowspan=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Recurring Total', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wcs_cart_totals_order_total_html( $recurring_cart ); ?></td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

and then you can print the number where ever you want inside the loop

```
<?php echo $i ?>
```

Comment: You have a typo in your for-loop. It should be `$i <= $n` but I do believe that a for-loop could mess up how woocommerce iterate through the items.